# How do i get my tabcontol text to update

Tags: c#, events, methods, tabcontrol

I am trying to this code in other methods

```
 e.Graphics.DrawString(Core.WebsiteName(FMainwb1), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
```

but the main problem is that there the event(i am not sure it is called ) e is there, so cant run it, so I thought to do this:

```
public void FMainwb1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{}

public void FMaintcMain_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{      
    e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right - 15, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Core.WebsiteName(FMainwb1), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();   
}
```

let me put the FMaintcMain_Drawitem method in the navigated. but I don't have a drawItemEventArgs. so i tried doing this:

```
public void FMainwb1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{      
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(Core.WebsiteName(FMainwb1), ev.Font, Brushes.Black, ev.Bounds.Left + 12, ev.Bounds.Top + 4);

}


public DrawItemEventArgs = ev;

public void FMaintcMain_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    ev = e
    e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right - 15, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Core.WebsiteName(FMainwb1), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle(); 
}
```

This seems to be the only way to make a close button on the tabcontrol.

Comment: oh i forgot this line is ment for updating the website name so.

Comment: Always tag you questions indicating your target: Winforms, WP, ASP etc.. so the right folks will look at it. Are you really talking about a winforms TabControl ?? It does have a DrawItem event called if you set the Tab to DrawMode=OwnerDrawxxx..